# No Module named 'Matplotlib' error in Python 3.6

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using Python 3.6 and I have miniconda. I have installed matplotlib using the command 'conda install matplotlib'. Courtsey other answers here, I also used the pip package to install matplotlib. However, when I try to import matplotlib on my Python Shell, it gives me a 'No Module named 'matplotlib' ' error. 
I have tried reinstalling my python and tried it with python 3.7 and the issue has persisted. 
None of the answers to other questions similar to this are working, what should I do? Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: Presumably the python shell you open is not the same as your miniconda interpreter

Comment: Did you try installing with pip3 or normal pip?

Comment: You could have multiple python installations. Make sure you are installing packages into and invoking the same one.